# How to Install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to this cloud services and recently I'm trying to deploy my PHP project using Microsoft SQL Server on Elastic Beanstalk. When I run it, it says :

> This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I already tried to install ODBC with config that I put at .ebextensions/pdo_sqlsrv.config.

```
###################################################################################################
#### Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
#### 
#### Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this
#### software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software
#### without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
#### merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
#### permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so.
###################################################################################################

###################################################################################################
#### THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
#### INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
#### PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
#### HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
#### OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
#### SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
###################################################################################################

commands:
  install_mssql:
    command: |
      #!/bin/bash

      # 0. EXIT if pdo_sqlsrv is already installed
      if php -m | grep -q 'pdo_sqlsrv'
      then
        echo 'pdo_sqlsrv is already installed'
      else
        # 1. Register the Microsoft Linux repository
        wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo

        # 2. Install MSSQL and tools
        ACCEPT_EULA=N yum install mssql-tools msodbcsql17 unixODBC-devel -y --disablerepo=amzn*
        sudo yum install unixODBC-utf16
        # The license terms for this product can be downloaded from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746949 and found in /usr/share/doc/mssql-tools/LICENSE.txt . By changing "ACCEPT_EULA=N" to "ACCEPT_EULA=Y", you indicate that you accept the license terms.
        echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
        echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
        source ~/.bashrc

        # 3. Install SQLSRV and its PDO extension, and stop pecl/pecl7 from overwriting php.ini
        cp -f "/etc/php.ini" "/tmp/php.ini.bk"
        pecl7 install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv || pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
        cp -f "/tmp/php.ini.bk" "/etc/php.ini"

        # 4. Manually add the extensions to the proper php.ini.d file and fix parameters
        sqlvar=$(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');") && chmod 0755 $sqlvar/sqlsrv.so && chmod 0755 $sqlvar/pdo_sqlsrv.so
        echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
        echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/20-sqlsrv.ini
      fi
      curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo1
      sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel
      sudo yum info unixODBC*
      sudo yum install mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
      echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' | tee -a ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

I've been searching and trying any command to install the ODBC, but still not working. Is there any way to install ODBC for SQL Server on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: SSH to the EB instance and run your commands manually to verify what works and where it fails.

Comment: SSH to the instance and execute `cat /etc/os-release` to figure out which specific distro (and version) of Linux it is. Then consult [Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac) to find the specific repo URLs and installation commands you need.

Comment: It is Amazon Linux 2 and it is based on Red Hat verison. I already tried using the Red Hat command version on the config, but still not working

Comment: @Marcin it is working when I do it manually, didnt know that I can do it manually. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marcin, I can solve this.

To solve this problem, I just need to ssh the instance and execute the command in the config manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ran this manually.  Unfortunately this wont be saved if AWS stands up a new server so still trying to figure out how to automate it as a "config" file doesn't work

```
sudo su

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#RHEL 7 and Oracle Linux 7
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

#RHEL 8 and Oracle Linux 8
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

#RHEL 9
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/9.0/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

exit
sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo yum install -y unixODBC-devel
```